# how to extract substring form a sequence using positions which are already in a tsv file

Tags: python-3.x, biopython

I'm trying to write a code that automatically extracts form a `tsv` file containing the start and end positions. And I want to use these positions to extract the substring form a `fasta` sequence.
I tried to do this :

```
import csv
import re

species_pos = '(\d* \d*)\D'
c_species_pos = re.compile(species_pos)

with open('/home/elissar/Documents/Fasta_sequences/start.tsv') as tsvfile:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for line in tsvreader:
        pos_found = re.findall(c_species_pos, re.Pattern)
        print(species_pos)
    tsvfile.close()
```

But it returns:

```
type error: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Your error message is typically part of a larger traceback that gives more information, such as exactly which line is throwing the error.  Could you post the full traceback?

Comment: Without seeing the full traceback (which I agree with @Hoog that you should post it for us to help you fully), I'd guess that your error comes from using `re.Pattern`, which should instead be `re.findall(c_species_pos, line)`. But this could be wrong because we don't know where the error is occurring.